# JSON format is not coming in rescue block - ruby

Tags: json, ruby, exception, rescue

```
require 'json'
begin
  hash = {"a" => "b"}
  raise StandardError, hash
rescue Exception => e
  q = e.message
  p q
  p q.to_json
end
```

it should print `"{\"a\":\"b\"}"` but it prints `"\"{\\\"a\\\"=>\\\"b\\\"}\""`. Any reason?

Comment: Use `puts`/`print` instead of `p`.

Comment: puts/prints gives {"a"=>"b"}"{\"a\"=>\"b\"}", not "{\"a\":\"b\"}"

Comment: if you execute `require 'json'
hash = {"a" => "b"}
print hash.to_json` then it prints {"a":"b"}. My question is why it does not print same when this is passed to rescue block

Comment: Because it is not a `Hash` anymore, it’s a `String` instance, `raise` casts it’s second argument to a string.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to the [`raise`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) method always treated as a string, so you can't have a hash from rescue, you can convert it to json and back

```
require 'json'
begin
  hash = {"a" => "b"}
  raise StandardError, hash.to_json # to string
rescue Exception => e
  q = JSON.parse(e.message)         # from string
  p q.to_json
end
=> "{\"a\":\"b\"}"
```

I also know evil-way with `eval`:

```
require 'json'
begin
  hash = {"a" => "b"}
  raise StandardError, hash
rescue Exception => e
  q = eval(e.message)
  p q.to_json
end
=> "{\"a\":\"b\"}"
```

But it is not good. Using `eval` It's really really bad.

Comment: Why not `JSON.parse`?

Comment: parse a string representation of hash?

Comment: Yes, try it yourself :)

Comment: @mudasobwa sure, why not? `require 'json';JSON.parse(%Q|{"a"=>"b"}|)` You must be kidding...